# How to allow "unfree" packages in Nix, for each situation?: {NixOS, Nix, Nix with Flakes, Nix with Flakes and Home Manager}

Tags: nix, nix-flake, home-manager

I'm trying to enable allow "unfree" packages, either globally or per-package, when using MyNixOS (excellent Flake configuration app for Nix) with Nix Flakes on Mac OS.

**When trying to install any unfree package after the following Flake update and Darwin rebuild command:**

```bash
cd ~/.nix/mynixos-nix-darwin-loader;
nix flake update;
darwin-rebuild switch --show-trace --flake .#name_of_my_config'
```

**I get the following help message, which isn't very helpful because it doesn't consider the Flake scenario:**

```
       error: Package ‘ec2-api-tools-1.7.5.1’ in /nix/store/${hash}-source/pkgs/tools/virtualization/e
c2-api-tools/default.nix:36 has an unfree license (‘amazonsl’), refusing to evaluate.

       a) To temporarily allow unfree packages, you can use an environment variable
          for a single invocation of the nix tools.

            $ export NIXPKGS_ALLOW_UNFREE=1

        Note: For `nix shell`, `nix build`, `nix develop` or any other Nix 2.4+
        (Flake) command, `--impure` must be passed in order to read this
        environment variable.

       b) For `nixos-rebuild` you can set
         { nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true; }
       in configuration.nix to override this.

       Alternatively you can configure a predicate to allow specific packages:
         { nixpkgs.config.allowUnfreePredicate = pkg: builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) [
             "ec2-api-tools"
           ];
         }

       c) For `nix-env`, `nix-build`, `nix-shell` or any other Nix command you can add
         { allowUnfree = true; }
       to ~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix.
```

Using MyNixOS downloads the following Flake file, and

`/nix/store/${hash}-source/homeConfigurations/my_flake_name.nix`:

```
{ inputs, ... }@flakeContext:
let
  homeModule = { config, lib, pkgs, ... }: {
    config = {
      home = {
        packages = [
          ec2-api-tools
          # ... (more packages)
        ];
        stateVersion = "23.11";
      };
      nixpkgs = {
        config = {
          allowUnfree = true;
          # allowUnfreePredicate = (_: true);
          allowUnfreePredicate = pkg: builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) [
            "ec2-api-tools"
          ];
        };
      };
# ... (the rest of the file)
```

Which results in a configuration path for the `allowUnfreePredicate` setting: `homeModule.config.nixpkgs.config.allowUnfreePredicate`. Does that seem correct?

This configuration seems to make no difference, and installing unfree packages always results in the same error.

**Exactly what needs to be done to allow unfree packages in each of these distinct scenarios?**

- NixOS
- Nix
- Nix with Flakes
- Nix with Flakes and Home Manager

*(Please edit the list or let me know if it doesn't make sense)*

**The advice from the following web pages didn't seem to apply, or I couldn't figure out how to apply it:**

- [NixOS Discourse: Allow unfree in flakes](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/allow-unfree-in-flakes/29904/2)
- [GitHub: nix-community/home-manager: #2942: bug: Flake config cannot use unfree packages despite nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true](https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager/issues/2942)
- [GitHub: nix-community/home-manager: #2720: modules/default.nix: Add useNixpkgsModule parameter](https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager/pull/2720)

  - Abandoned merge request

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `let` binding in your `flake.nix` to define the list of unfree packages you want to allow. Then you can use `specialArgs` to pass it to all NixOS modules, and [extraSpecialArgs](https://nix-community.github.io/home-manager/index.xhtml#sec-install-nixos-module) to pass it to all Home Manager modules.

Here is how I do it in my `flake.nix`:

```
{
  description = "My NixOS & Home Manager configuration";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "https://flakehub.com/f/NixOS/nixpkgs/*.tar.gz";

    home-manager = {
      url = "github:nix-community/home-manager/release-23.11";
      inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
    };
  };

  outputs = {
    home-manager,
    nixpkgs,
    self,
    ...
  } @ inputs: let
    system = "x86_64-linux";
    user = "jack";

    # Define the list of unfree packages to allow here, so you can pass it to
    # both `sudo nixos-rebuild` and `home-manager`
    allowed-unfree-packages = [
      "google-chrome"
      "obsidian"
      "postman"
      "vscode"
      "vscode-extension-github-copilot"
    ];
  in {
    nixosConfigurations."nixos-laptop" = nixpkgs.lib.nixosSystem {
      inherit system;

      modules = [
        ./nixos/hosts/my-nixos-laptop/configuration.nix
        home-manager.nixosModules.home-manager
        {
          home-manager.useGlobalPkgs = true;
          home-manager.useUserPackages = true;
          home-manager.users.${user} = import ./home-manager/users/${user}.nix;
          home-manager.extraSpecialArgs = {inherit allowed-unfree-packages user;};
        }
      ];

      specialArgs = {inherit allowed-unfree-packages user;};
    };

    # Standalone home-manager configuration entrypoint
    # Available through 'home-manager --flake .#username@hostname'
    homeConfigurations."${user}@nixos-laptop" = home-manager.lib.homeManagerConfiguration {
      pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
      extraSpecialArgs = {inherit allowed-unfree-packages user;};
      modules = [
        ./home-manager/users/${user}.nix
      ];
    };
  };
}
```

This way `allowed-unfree-packages` will be available as an input in **all** of your **NixOS modules** (because you passed it via `specialArgs`) and **all** of your **Home Manager modules** (because you passed it via `extraSpecialArgs`). So you will be able to configure nixpkgs like this:

```
{
  allowed-unfree-packages,
  config,
  lib,
  pkgs,
  ...
}: {
  nixpkgs.config = {
    allowUnfreePredicate = pkg: builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) allowed-unfree-packages;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `nixpkgs.config` in a `homeModule` wouldn't make sense here; as you appear to be using `nix-darwin` with HM as a system module, you'll have to configure `nixpkgs` at the system level, not within an HM module.